# Create Directory with win32 means

Tags: c++, winapi

Need help with directory's creation using shlwapi.dll and shfolder.dll.

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
char buffer[]="My\Folder";
char *lpStr;
lpStr=buffer;

if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, 
                             CSIDL_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
                             NULL,
                             0,
                             szPath)))
{
    PathAppend(szPath, lpStr);
    SHCreateDirectory(0, L"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\My\Folder");
}
```

Do I really need PathAppend? Is it a proper code and if not, what I need to emedate?

Comment: For one, you need to escape those back-slashes; *all* of them.

Comment: For another, misspelling "Settings" would be another really good reason.

Comment: For third, if you're going to expend all that effort to calculate `szPath`, it's a shame that you never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this instead:

```
WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, 
                             CSIDL_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
                             NULL,
                             0,
                             szPath)))
{
    PathAppendW(szPath, L"My\\Folder");
    SHCreateDirectory(0, szPath);
}
```